# How to calculate an integral involving square roots and trigonometric functions?

Tags: integration

I am waiting for the response since 2009.
This question was asked by my teacher.

$\displaystyle \int \mathrm{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Do you mean to ask if $\int\!\sqrt{\sin x}\,dx$ has an elementary antiderivative?

Comment: What have you tried to answer this question ? Have you read some books, looked into antiderivative tables ? If you don't mention what you investigated, someone may start the same way you did... and lose its time.

Comment: Wolframalpha gives an answer involving an elliptic integral, so I don't think there's an antiderivative of $\sqrt{\sin{x}}$ in terms of elementary functions

Comment: I am asking for the answer . it is possible then told me answer.

Comment: Since 2009 ? That's a long time ! Don't wait any longer : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%28sin%28x%29%29